# Google Apps Script: Как получить DeveloperMetadata всех столбцов или всех строк на листе?

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть таблица, в которой к определенным строкам и столбцам прописаны DeveloperMetadata.
Как скриптом можно получить все эти метаданные? Чтобы не перебирать все столбцы и строки.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы должны использовать метод [search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search) из Google Sheets API.

Попробуйте просто создать [DeveloperMetadataFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createDeveloperMetadataFinder()) для Range/Sheet. И дернуть его метод [find()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata-finder#find()).

По ссылке [DeveloperMetadataFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createDeveloperMetadataFinder()) более-менее внятный пример. А в массиве уже перебирайте результаты, создавая релевантную выборку. Другого варианта не просматривается  ‍♂️.